# Triple DES with CBC mode : java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 8 bytes long

Tags: java, encryption, 3des, cbc-mode, block-cipher

I am trying to implement a 3DES encryption/decryption with CBC mode in java. 
The initialisation vector is 0000000000000000

Encrypted string is DD446C051A83BFD98144C348935C61D81398CF29CCFE1CCD

Key for decryption is DCBA4F836E45BAB04FAB2937454075D9
I am receiving below error. 
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 8 bytes long
```

Code:

```
import java.security.Key; 

import javax.crypto.Cipher; 
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory; 
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec; 
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; 

public class DES3 { 

    private static final String IV = "01234567"; 
    private static final String CHARSET = "utf-8"; 

    public static String decrypt(String iv, String secretKey, String encryptText) throws Exception { 
        DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes()); 
        SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede"); 
        Key deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec); 
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("desede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
        IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes()); 
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, deskey, ips); 
        byte[] decryptData = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptText)); 
        return new String(decryptData, CHARSET); 
    } 

    public static String decrypt(String secretKey, String encryptText) throws Exception { 
        return decrypt(IV, secretKey, encryptText); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String iv="0000000000000000";
            System.out.println("iv size"+iv.getBytes("UTF8").length);
            decrypt(iv, "DCBA4F836E45BAB04FAB2937454075D9", "DD446C051A83BFD98144C348935C61D81398CF29CCFE1CCD");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: 1. It is time to learn binary and encodings such as hexadecimal (hex), Base64, ASCII and UTF-8. 2. An IV of all zeros (0x00) is not secure, instead use a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is here:

```
 String iv="0000000000000000";
```

which shows your IV is hex string. But in your decrypt function you use:

```
iv.getBytes()
```

for this IV. This is obviously over 16 bytes long. **You need to convert hex string to byte, not only use `getBytes()` function**. `getBytes()` convert each chat to corresponding ASCII code, so you will get an array of 16 bytes each `0x30`, rather than getting an array of 8 bytes each `0`.

By the way, you have same problem for your secret key and your input too.

You can check [hexStringToByteArray()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) here.

Comment: Thanks. I kept this because I believe 3DES decryption uses 16 bytes IV.
I have decrypted the values in my code in an online decrypter. It uses 16 bytes. Any thoughts please? Thanks
Please check the link: http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/link/11da349gxUIcgKonRz/

Comment: @Preetam you are wrong. both DES and 3DES have block and IV size equal to 8, not 16. An small search shows this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES 3DES is just using DES for 3 times, it does not change IV or block size. In addition, in link that you sent me IV is 8 bytes too...<.<